# Compare two files and update IDs

Tags: python, xml

Currently, I'm working with two XML files: One file with text, where each word has its ID, the other file consists of the IDs of 'special' words such as names. Here is an example of file 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book id="book.mul">
  <article author="Test" id="a1" lang="de" title="Example">
    <div>
      <s id="a1-s1" lang="en">
        <w head="ROOT" id="a1-s1-w1" lemma="Example" pos="NN">Example</w>
      </s>
    </div>
    <div>
      <s id="a1-s2" lang="en">
        <w deprel="DET" head="a1-s2-w2" id="a1-s2-w1" lemma="d" pos="ART">This</w>
        <w deprel="SUBJ" head="a1-s2-w4" id="a1-s2-w2" lemma="be" pos="VAFIN">is</w>
        <w deprel="APP" head="a1-s2-w2" id="a1-s2-w3" lemma="John" pos="NE">John</w>
        <w deprel="-PUNCT-" head="a1-s2-w3" id="a1-s2-w4" lemma=";" pos="$.">;</w>
      </s>
    </div>
  </article>
</book>
```

Here is an example of file 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ner>
  <per>
    <g id="g_1" level="per" span="a1-s2-w3" stid="s23" type="person"/>
    <g id="g_2" level="per" span="a1-s2-w17" stid="g23" type="person"/>
  </per>
</ner>
```

Now my idea is to go through all entries in file 2 and to check whether the "span" corresponds to an ID in file 1. If this is the case, the POS-tag in file 1 has to be "NE". In this case, everything seems to be OK.

If the POS-tag is not equal to "NE", I'd like to check whether the previous word in file 1 has the POS-tag "NE". If this is the case, I'd like to change the span-ID in the second file.

How can this be done in an efficient way?

(Why searching backwards? Because there are some operations which may remove an entry...and in fact, it is possible that up to 3 entries per sentence are removed. Is this possible to implement this in such a way?)

And of course, if you see other ways to solve the problem, I'd be interested to hear them. ;)

Thanks a lot for any proposition!

Edit:

My actual function looks like this one:

```
def correct_tags(root):
    for sentence in root.findall('.//s'):
        words = sentence.findall('.//w')
        sent_lang = sentence.get('lang')
        if sent_lang == 'de':
            for index, word in enumerate(words):
                try:
                    # correct 's in German texts (attach to previous word if previous word = NE
                    if word.text == "'s" and words[index-1].get('pos') in ['NE', 'NN']:
                        print('word before', words[index-1].text)
                        text = words[index-1].text
                        words[index-1].text = text + "'s"
                        print('word after', words[index-1].text)
                        try:
                            sentence.remove(word)
                        except ValueError:
                            print('not working', word)

                except IndexError:
                    continue
```

You can see in the code that I remove an entry and that this is the cause for the different IDs which should be equal. Is it maybe possible / nicer / more efficient to directly check the differences in the two XMLs?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this one works for me although it's not optimized, but you can give it a try:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree1 = ET.parse('file1.xml')
tree2 = ET.parse('file2.xml')

w_elements = tree1.findall('.//w')
w_ids = [w.attrib['id'] for w in w_elements]
g_elements = tree2.findall('.//g')
g_spans = [g.attrib['span'] for g in g_elements]

print(g_spans)

for i, span in enumerate(g_spans):
     for j, id_ in enumerate(w_ids):
          if id_ == span:
               print('Found matching id and span -- [{} - {}]'.format(id_, span))
               print('`pos` attribute of matching elements: [{}]'.format(w_elements[j].attrib['pos']))
               if w_elements[j].attrib['pos'] != 'NE':
                    print('`pos` not equals \'NE\' for element with id [{}]'.format(id_))
                    try:
                         print('Checking previous elements `pos` attribute...')
                         if w_elements[j-1].attrib['pos'] == 'NE':
                              print('Previous element\'s `pos` attribute is matching.')
                              g_elements[i].attrib['span'] = w_ids[j-1]
                    except IndexError:
                         print('IndexError raised at index [{}].'.format(j))



print([g.attrib['span'] for g in g_elements])
```

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot! :) 
Your code works for me as well! I will add an update, because maybe there is also another solution?

Comment: I uploaded here a quite similar problem...could you please also have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265458/change-id-and-update-the-following-ones